# Deserialize php object in amazon redshift using string functions

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift in which a column is a PHP serialized object. I want to use redshift string functions and de-serialize the column and make another temporary table with the deserialized values.
for example: 
the initial table would look like

`| col A               | 
|a:1:{i:145;s:2:"14";} | 
|a:1:{i:145;s:2:"15";} | 
|a:1:{i:145;s:2:"16";} |`

The expected output temporary table for further processing is:

`| Col A | Col B | 
 | 145   | 14    | 
 | 145   | 15    | 
 | 145   | 16    |`

How can I use redshift string functions to deserialize this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your particular case it would work like this:

```
select 
 split_part(split_part('a:1:{i:145;s:2:"14";}',':',4),';',1)
,trim(split_part(split_part('a:1:{i:145;s:2:"14";}',':',6),';',1),'"');
```

if there can be other formats of this structure this isn't going to work

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with:

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(SPLIT_PART(VALUE,';',1),'[^:]*$') as fieldName1,
trim('"' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(SPLIT_PART(VALUE,';',2),'[^:]*$')) as fieldName2;`